# Revert Index Location to Default

Tags: 2013, powershell, search, index-component

In SP2013, if you use a method such as [this one](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Move-SharePoint-2013-242869e2) to change the location of your search index, is there an easy way to revert it to the default location? Or do you have to do the whole process again and change the path back to its original value manually? By "easy way" I'm thinking of like `New-SPEnterpriseSearchIndexComponent -RootDirectory Default` that will pick the location automatically and remove the possibility of human error.